# ArrayList get() method to find class variable?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a list of a class type. For example, I have a ClassRoom class and a Student class.

I created an ArrayList of Students: `ArrayList<Student> studList = new ArrayList<>();`

I have a method to add a student, so index 0 is occupied:

```java
    public void addStudent(int studID, String studName, int studPhoneNum){
        Student stud = new Student(studName, studID, studPhoneNum);
        studList.add(stud);
        System.out.println(studList);
    }
```

Now what I want is to search for a specific value inside the student's variables. So for example, a student is represented by a name, ID and phone number. How do I loop over that Student list to find a student with a specific phone number, then print him or his phone number?

This is the function:

```java
    public void sendMessage(int phone){
        for (Student s : studList) {
            studList.get(studPhoneNum);
            \\ then print the Student the phone number belongs to..
        }
    }
```

I do have a `studPhoneNum` variable set in the Student class.

Comment: `if(s.getPhonenumber == phone)`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't find this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a function to get the phone number like this:

```
public int getPhoneNumber(int stuID){
    for (Student s: studList) {
        if(s.id == stuID){
            return s.phoneNumber;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm supposing here that stuList is a global variable since you can access to it in addStudent without passing it as an argument, otherwise you'll have to pass it to the function. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the whole `s.something` thing. This works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are iterating over studList, 's' represents every individual student in that list.

```
public void sendMessage(int phone){
    for (Student s : studList) {
        if (s.getStudPhoneNum() == phone){
             System.out.print(s.getStudName());
        }
    }
}
```

Here you would need to create getter methods (getStudPhoneNumber(), getStudName())to refer attributes of the Student class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below:

1. Using Java 8 stream:

   ```
   studList.stream()
           .filter(student -> student.getStudPhoneNum==studPhone)
           .findFirst()
           .ifPresent(student -> {
               // Do something
           });
   ```
2. Using for loop:

   ```
   for(Student s: studList){
       if(s.getStudPhoneNum==studPhone){
           //do something
       }
   }
   ```